# Batch Script for deployment in oracle weblogic sever 11g

Tags: shell, deployment, oracle11g, ear

Can anyone  please share the sample  batch script code for deploying ear file to a **oracle  weblogic server 11g**?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved using shell script alone. A shell script in conjunction with WLST to be used to achieve this. In Shell script setup WLST environment and invoke WLST script. Please have a look at below answer for sample WLST script.

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601680/wldeploy-on-all-files-in-deployment-folder/41621500#41621500
```